# Catch first match with Regex - PYTHON

Tags: python, regex

Regex is separating into groups, not selecting first match

**REGEX**

```
([^:.]+)
```

**DATA**

```
DATA1:OS
DATA2-XT
DATA3.DOMAIN.COM.BR
```

**GOAL**

```
DATA1
DATA2-XT
DATA3
```

[REGEX101](https://regex101.com/r/dXY7i2/1)

Comment: Add a start anchor `^` in the beginning of the regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('[^:.]+')
str_list = ["DATA1:OS",
            "DATA2-XT",
            "DATA3.DOMAIN.COM.BR"]
for e in str_list:
    print(pattern.match(e).group())
```